# Select random row which is limited, and at the same time display information from other table which is based on a displayed random row (PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, select, random

I am not good at php, so maybe you guys can help me? Lets say that i have two tables.

[image]

**number1**

[image]

**number2**

[image]

**PHP code**

```
<?php

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=****;charset=utf8', '***', '***');

$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM number1, number2 ORDER by rand() LIMIT 1');

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

echo '<div class="city">';
echo '<div class="city-name">'.$row['city'].'</div>';
echo '<div class="city-information">'.$row['information'].'</div>';
echo '<div style="background:url(img/'.$row['city'].'.jpg)"></div>';
echo '</div>';

}

?>
```

I think that this code is bad, but i dont know how to do this properly.

**Question**

Select random row which is limited, and at the same time display information from other table which is based on a displayed random row. I mean that if for example Vienna (from number1 table) is displayed, than ***all*** information from *number2* which has Vienna attribute (i dont know how to say) should be displayed.

Sorry for bad english, and thanks to all of you to any of answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a join:

```
SELECT n2.city, GROUP_CONCAT(n2.information) AS information
FROM (SELECT city
      FROM number1
      ORDER BY RAND()
      LIMIT 1) AS n1
JOIN number2 AS n2 ON n1.city = n2.city
```

Also, you don't need a `while` loop when the query only returns 1 row.

Comment: I am getting this error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in` . Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Sorry, `RANDOM()` should be `RAND()`. Enable error signaling in PDO so you see the MySQL error.

Comment: Now it is working. Thank you very much! I have one question to you: how to display only once a city name and all information from that city?

Comment: See the updated query, I concatenate all the information together.

Comment: Getting same error as previous :/ and i dont have any images or path in table :|

Comment: Sorry, I misread the code in your question, I thought there was an image.

Comment: You still aren't looking at the SQL syntax errors, apparently. Since it would have told you that that was the problem and you could have fixed it yourself.

Comment: YEYJ! thank you so much! its working now perfectly :) !!! Is this php code correct, safe.. etc? :)

Comment: The PHP code is OK except for the unnecessary `while` loop. There's execatly one row, why do you need to loop over them?

Comment: Well, i am not good at php, so i dont know why, i just used this tutorial: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers . I will use this only in local network.

Comment: The examples there are performing queries that return multiple records, and displaying all of them. How good do you have to be to know what "while" is for for doing things multiple times, and it doesn't make sense in other cases?

Comment: You need to think about what you're doing, not just copy code blindly.

Comment: I will think about that. I guarantee that to you. Thanks again and good luck!